# Codeigniter no data sent posted on form

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My login system suddenly stopped working, I can't fix it, I've been looking into it and it seems that the data doesn't get posted back but I can't find the problem.

This is my view:

```
    <?php if(! is_null($err)) echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">".$err."</div>";?>
    <form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo site_url("user/validate"); ?>" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <br/>
    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br/>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my my validate function inside the user controller:

```
public function validate()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    // Load the model
    echo "$email and $password sent";
    print_r($this->input->post());
    exit();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    // Validate user's login details
    $result = $this->User_model->validate($email, $password);
    // Now we verify the result
    if($result == 0){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $err = 'Invalid email and/or password.';
        $this->login($err);
    }else{
        // If user did validate send him to homepage after setting the credentials
        $this->session->set_userdata($result);
        redirect(site_url("/index/index"));
    }
}
```

the echo and the print_r show that no data is posted.

After some research I found out that the problem should be the .htaccess file, this is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

But it's not working.

Comment: No, $this->input->post() is just empty

Comment: That means that your form action is wrong because the values does not go to the validate function

Comment: Check the path of the form action

Comment: If you have index.php in your url, use site_url(), If you don't have index.php in your url, use base_url().

Answer (score 0):

1. you have an `exit();` in validate function comment it
2. try : `if(!empty( $err ))`
3. try : `base_url("index.php/user/validate");`
4. try : load model inside

   `public function __construct()`

   not inside of

   `public function validate()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I reach that function, the problem is that $this->input->post() is completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo site_url("user/validate"); ?>" method="post">
```

Change this to the following:

```
<form class='form-signin' action="<?php echo base_url();?>user/validate" method="post" name="user_from">
```

Also don't use the submit button name as 'submit'. Just use sbt or other name, id too...